# Is static variables are Thread specific in java?

Tags: java

Is static variables are Thread specific, means

```
class A {
    public static int i = 10;
} 

Class B {
    A.i = 20;
}

Class C {
    A.i = 30;
}

Class D {
    System.out.println(A.i);
}
```

Above classes I am calling from my web application, i.e. in first request I Call Class B, in second request I call Class B and in third request I have called Class D. Now what it will print 10/20/30?

Thank You.

Comment: Your example code doesn't even compile. Please shows us compiling code.

Comment: I don't think compiling sample code is required. Its not unusual for people to post stripped down versions of their code. What's important is that your are able to get a good sense of what they are trying to do. Which in this case you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer to your question (will it print 10/20/30?), assuming that each request might be processed by a different thread, is "yes".

Logically, if each of those requests happen in chronological order, and each in a different thread, then you would see 20 (the value is not thread-specific, which I think you're asking), but note that even if the call to D happens chronologically last, it could still see the value '10'; the field is neither final nor volatile, so the Java Memory Model makes no guarantees about WHEN the change to 20 will be visible to other threads.

Answer (score 5):

No, use [ThreadLocal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) for that.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, They are *loaded class* specific

Answer (score 1):

static variable are global and shared across threads. this means that in your example (B -> C -> D) d will print 30 (only if they are called in that order

this has some issues for synchronization you might wanna be aware of...

Answer (score 0):

Static variables are global that means you can make changes on them wherever you want and variable will has the final value that you assigned to it.In a method if the variable is private you make changes but out of the method that variable will has same value before the method's calculate.Eventually this code will show you 30.